# Listening to events from another library in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, fabricjs

I create a FabricJS object in a context provider and store it into the context:

```
const [canvas, setCanvas] = useState(false);

const initCanvas = (c) => {
    setCanvas(new fabric.Canvas(c));
    console.log('Canvas initialized', canvas);
}
```

When the canvas component has mounted, I call this initCanvas() function.

```
useEffect(() => {
    context.initCanvas('c');
}, []);
```

FabricJS offers an event listener with a variety of events to listen to. For instance canvas.on('object:added', handler) gets fired when an object gets added to the canvas. I want to use canvas.getObjects() method from Fabric to update the object list into the context

```
useEffect(() => {
    if(canvas) {
        setObjectList(canvas.getObjects());
    }
    console.log("ObjectList:", objectList);
}, [canvas]); //??
```

How can I update a ReactJS component, when an event happens in Fabric?

Answer (score 2):

```js
useEffect(()=> {
   if (!canvas) {return;}
   function handleChange(){
     setObjectList(canvas.getObjects());
   }
   handleChange(); // initialize 
   canvas.on("object:added", handleChange);
   return ()=> {
     canvas.off("object:added");
   }
}, [canvas])
```